# Dockerized App: Socket Timeout Error During npm Install

Tags: docker, npm, build, proxy, npm-install

**Description:**
I'm facing a socket timeout error while trying to run `npm install` in a Dockerized  application. This issue seems related to network connectivity or proxy settings within the Docker container. Here are the details:

**Problem Details:**
I have a  application containerized with Docker. When I run the `npm install` command within the container, it proceeds with several warnings about deprecated packages and then encounters a socket timeout error. The error message suggests that it might be related to network connectivity issues or proxy settings.

**Tags:**

- Docker
- Node.js
- npm
- Socket Timeout
- Network Connectivity
- Proxy Settings

**Error Log:**

```
PS D:\opensource\p5.js-web-editor> docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml build
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.4s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 826B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16.14.2                                                                                    2.8s
 => [app base 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.14.2@sha256:6e54786b2ad01667d46524e82806298714f50d2be72b39706770aed55faedbd7                         0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                  0.3s
 => => transferring context: 29.48kB                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [app base 2/3] RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [app base 3/3] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [app development 1/9] COPY package.json package-lock.json ./                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [app development 2/9] RUN npm install                                                                                                       76.6s
------
 > [app development 2/9] RUN npm install:
29.73 npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
34.95 npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
49.97 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
49.98 npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
54.56 npm WARN deprecated bson@1.0.9: Fixed a critical issue with BSON serialization documented in CVE-2019-2391,  for more details
64.17 npm notice
64.17 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.5.0 -> 10.1.0
64.17 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.1.0>
64.17 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.1.0` to update!
64.17 npm notice
64.17 npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
64.17 npm ERR! network Socket timeout
64.17 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
64.17 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
64.18 npm ERR! network
64.18 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
64.18 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
64.20
64.20 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
64.20 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-10-01T18_08_51_668Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

**Review:**
I've encountered a socket timeout error while running `npm install` in a Dockerized Node.js application. I've provided details about the problem, what I've tried, and relevant tags. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i have tried deleting the folder and again fork it and run the command it didn't work.